# R ENTSO-E API Request leads to repeating values

Tags: r, xml

I have set up an API with ENTSEO following, for example, this solution:

- [Using data from API requests with text/XML format in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71429362/using-data-from-api-requests-with-text-xml-format-in-r)

Everything works as intended. The receiving data has the wanted structure. However, for the interesting data points (positions and quantity) the values keep repeating themselves. Could you please help me find the issue with my code? Thank you!

When I am entering the URL into a browser the resulting data is the following:

```xml
<Point>
  <position>1</position>
  <quantity>5872</quantity>
</Point>
<Point>
  <position>2</position>
  <quantity>5784</quantity>
</Point>
<Point>
  <position>3</position>
  <quantity>5690</quantity>
</Point>
```

In R the data would look the following way:

```xml
<Point>
  <position>1</position>
  <quantity>5872</quantity>
</Point>
<Point>
  <position>1</position>
  <quantity>5872</quantity>
</Point>
<Point>
  <position>1</position>
  <quantity>5872</quantity>
</Point>
```

My code is the following:

```r
 url <- "https://web-api.tp.entsoe.eu/api?securityToken=X&documentType=A65&processType=A16&outBiddingZone_Domain=10YCZ-CEPS-----N&periodStart=201512312300&periodEnd=201612312300"
  
 request <- GET(url = url, securityToken="X")
  
 raw_xml <- httr::content(request, encoding = "UTF-8")

 output_list <- xml2::as_list(raw_xml)
```

Comment: By "would look" , do you mean this is what you'd get when re-building XML from parsed results?  What about actual raw XML content? Can you include XML responses from both browser and R sessions (e.g. output from  `GET(url) |> content(as = "text") |> cat()` or  `read_xml(url) |> as.character() |> cat()` ) ? You can reduce the output by changing 
 `periodEnd` so it would be closer to `periodStart`.

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry, the solution is very easy. While when I click on the output_list and see it in the R Studio data window the values are repeating themselves, the real data (e.g. from GET(url) |> content(as = "text") |> cat() has changing values). The data window from R Studio seems to not display the data correctly.

Comment: If the actual response matches the one in example ( https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/7009892/2s93JtP3F6#b223e451-65c9-4e24-a782-2af31b431742 ) I'm not able to reproduce that behaviour. Though if you are just after `Point` elements, I'd rather extract those with xml2 first.

Comment: Thank you as well. Please have a look at my answer below and the two pictures. The issues lies with how R Studio presents the data. Sorry that the issue was so trivial in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simpel. R Studio seems to not display the raw data correctly. Using, e.g., `GET(url) |> content(as = "text") |> cat()` shows that the underlying data is the same as in the browser. Therefore, the issue lies with R Studio not displaying the data correctly.
[image]

[image]